# My blender's universal motor shoots micro sparks from the outer coil. Is that normal?

Tags: electrical, appliances, electric-motor

I recently fixed a 767 blender (re-branded) and I've noticed that whenever I engage the safety switch without turning on its motor, it shoots a tiny spark from the inner edge of the outer coil (or whatever is the name of that thing) - see pics bellow.

Do I need to worry it might burn the house down in case one day I forgot and leave the power point switch on?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I wonder if the motor isn't acting as a generator.

Comment: If you're meaning you're seeing arcing where you drew the little red square, I will help make clear this mystery --- You should NOT see arcing in that area for ANY reason at ANY time.   With due respect, I'll say your 'repair' is not solid.  The reasons why could be many... Not sure what you did to it.   I would say, make it stop arcing or replace it.   Looks like MAYBE the coil wire is touching the housing?  (about 1/2" below the red square)   It shouldn't be....

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know that I should not be seeing arcing at all. I need to do some research on how do what has been suggested below and see if that stops it. The wires are not touching the housing, it's like that on the picture because I haven't put them back at the time I took it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix arcing in a field winding.

Spread those windings out and reapply armature varnish or Glyptal as needed.

Comment: Right! do you have any tutorials to recommend on how to do that?